# Class cannot be cast to ParameterizedType

Tags: java, reflection

```
public class FrontUtil<T> {

    public List<Map<String, String>> tableGen(List<Map<String, String>> theads, List<T> tbodys){


        List<Map<String, String>> frontList = null;

        for (T t : tbodys) {
            *Class<T> clazz =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];*
            for (Map<String, String> title : theads) {
                try {
                    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(title.get("columnClass"));
                    PropertyDescriptor pd = new PropertyDescriptor(field.getName(), clazz);
                    Method getMethod = pd.getReadMethod();
                    String content = getMethod.invoke(t).toString();
                    Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>(0);
                    temp.put(title.get("columnName"), content);
                    frontList.add(temp);
                }  catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return frontList;
    }
}
```

the stack：

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    *****FrontUtil.tableGen(FrontUtil.java:19)
    *****action.MaterialFactoryAction.list(MaterialFactoryAction.java:78)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I  would like to get the Actual class of T though

```
Class<T> clazz =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

but it can't work . Any suggestion would be appreciated,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: you can't. Because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) that information no longer exists at run time.

Pass in a `Class` argument when you create your `FrontUtil` instance.

```
private Class<T> clazz;
public FrontUtil(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}
```

Then use that `Class` object wherever you need it.

Comment: it worked there is a new problem.  object is not an instance of declaring class .on the line of  'String content = getMethod.invoke(t).toString();' could you help me? I try clazz.newInstance() to replace 't' but log show nullpointer on line of it. Thanks.

Comment: I test System.out.println(getMethod.invoke(clazz.newInstance()));It print null;

Comment: @pandita Can you edit your question to add what you are now trying to do?